# how can I find the cookies files to specific websites?

Tags: firefox, files, filesystem

I am using firefox, but I dont really care what browser I use, I just want to find the cookies file to a specific website I am going to. I think the cookies file will tell me things like how I can stay logged in. I want to write a script to log in via PHP or wget, but I cant seem to find the cookie for the web page.

I tried clearing the history using bleachbit, thinking this would reduce the number of files in the .mozilla folder, but there is still many files there, and I cannot  find the file I am looking for.

How can I find the cookies file for a website?

The url, if it matters is:
https://www.spytecgps.io/spytecgps/client_login.php?r=8067

Comment: Is this helpful? https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1218110

Answer (score 1):

I did (for `firefox`, but in principle, most of it (down to the `file` command) should work for any browser):

```
# Find firefox's cookie files
$ sudo lsof -c firefox | grep "$HOME.\*cookies"
firefox 5495 walt  mem-r     REG               0,48     32768 13243731 /home/walt/.mozilla/firefox/gbqd07qo.default/cookies.sqlite-shm
firefox 5495 walt   41ur     REG               0,48   1572864 13245306 /home/walt/.mozilla/firefox/gbqd07qo.default/cookies.sqlite
firefox 5495 walt   46u      REG               0,48    590288 13243730 /home/walt/.mozilla/firefox/gbqd07qo.default/cookies.sqlite-wal
firefox 5495 walt   48ur     REG               0,48     32768 13243731 /home/walt/.mozilla/firefox/gbqd07qo.default/cookies.sqlite-shm
#
# What are these files?
$ file .mozilla/firefox/gbqd07qo.default/cookies.sqlite*
.mozilla/firefox/gbqd07qo.default/cookies.sqlite:     SQLite 3.x database, user version 9
.mozilla/firefox/gbqd07qo.default/cookies.sqlite-shm: data
.mozilla/firefox/gbqd07qo.default/cookies.sqlite-wal: SQLite Write-Ahead Log, version 3007000
# Use `sqlite3` (from package `sqlite3) to explore.
# One probably should kill firefox before doing anything to change the database 
$ sqlite3 .mozilla/firefox/gbqd07qo.default/cookies.sqlite '.tables'
moz_cookies
$ sqlite3 .mozilla/firefox/gbqd07qo.default/cookies.sqlite '.schema moz_cookies'
CREATE TABLE "moz_cookies" (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, baseDomain TEXT, originAttributes TEXT NOT NULL DEFAULT '', name TEXT, value TEXT, host TEXT, path TEXT, expiry INTEGER, lastAccessed INTEGER, creationTime INTEGER, isSecure INTEGER, isHttpOnly INTEGER, inBrowserElement INTEGER DEFAULT 0, sameSite INTEGER, CONSTRAINT moz_uniqueid UNIQUE (name, host, path, originAttributes));
CREATE INDEX moz_basedomain ON moz_cookies (baseDomain, originAttributes);
```

Extracting the cookie data is left as an exercise for the student.

Comment: For navigation in SQLite database [`sqliteman`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&exact=1&searchon=names&keywords=sqliteman) may be used. It is GUI application.

Answer (score 0):

Just open Firefox Preferences - at the top you'll see a search bar. Type in 'cookies' and you'll be presented with tabs - select 'manage cookies'. In the following dialogue use the search field to find the cookies you're looking for. Pretty slick.